# Node.js cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I try to use a global function where i can use for some mysql functions, but the problem is that js say that the ".then" is undefined, what make i wrong, is this only an syntax error?

```
 static connectWidthCortex(){
  xdevapi.getSession({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 33060,
        dbUser: 'admin',
        dbPassword: 'xxxx'
    }).then((session)=> {
  return session.getSchema("cortex");
});
};

static createCollection(collname){
    this.connectWidthCortex().then((db)=> {
  console.log("Cortex connected")
  return db.createCollection(collname);
}).catch((err)=> {
  console.log("connection failed")
});
}
```

Thx for help :)

Comment: I am guessing the return value of `connectWidthCortex()` isn't a promise. Can you check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to call `then` on the return value of `connectWidthCortex`.

The `connectWidthCortex` function **doesn't have a `return` statement**, so it returns `undefined`.

If you want to return the promise that calling `getSession` gives you, then you need a `return` statement.

`return xdevapi.getSession({ …`